# Magento Block Not Working - 1.9.2.2

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, module, block

I've created a custom extension and I'm trying to render a custom block. However, I see nothing.

My code is as follows;

**app/code/local/Gdaze/Megamenu/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gdaze_Megamenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Gdaze_Megamenu>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <megamenu>
                <class>Gdaze_Megamenu_Block</class>
            </megamenu>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Gdaze/Megamenu/Block/Customblock.php**

```
<?php
  class Gdaze_Megamenu_Block_Customblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
  {

  }
?>
```

**app/design/frontend/rwd/site/gdaze/megamenu.phtml**

```
<?php echo "Works"; ?>
```

My method of calling the block.

```
<?php $this->getLayout()->createBlock('megamenu/customblock')->setTemplate('gdaze/megamenu.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

I don't really understand what's happening here. I've tried whitelisting the block (a new problem since 1.9.2.2) by adding megamenu/customblock. I've googled the cr*p out of this, but everything suggested just doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something really obvious? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the module configuration on the etc/modules folder?

Comment: Yep, the module displays fine in admin=>system=>advanced, I just can't seem to get it to do anything :(

Comment: Do you get any errors in your log file?

Comment: That is another, albeit seperate issue that I'm having in that my logs aren't working. Both system.log and exception.log are emtpy, despite having logging turned on and having correct file permissions. I know that's uphelpful, sorry!

Comment: Okay, system.log is now working but is displaying a problem that seems to be independent of this. No errors regarding the above.

Comment: What about the expection.log?

Comment: Still empty after clearing cache and reloading the page a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was a bit of an idiot. In my calling statement, I neglected to echo the results.

```
<?php ***echo*** $this->getLayout()->createBlock('megamenu/customblock')->setTemplate('gdaze/megamenu.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```